# cannot run jupyter notebook from anaconda but able to run it from python

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

After installing Anaconda to `C:\` I cannot open jupyter notebook. Both in the Anaconda Prompt with `jupyter notebook` and inside the navigator. I just can't make it to work. It doesn't appear any line when I type `jupyter notebook` iniside the prompt. Neither does the navigator work. Then after that I reinstall Anaconda, didn't work either.

But then I try to reinstall jupyter notebook dependently using `python -m install jupyter` and then run `python -m jupyter`. It works and connect to the `localhost:8888`. So my question is that how can I make Jupyter works from Anaconda
Also note that my anaconda is not in the environment variable( or %PATH% ) and I have tried reinstalling `pyzmq` and it didn't solve the problem. I'm using Python 3.7 and 3.6.5 in Anaconda

Moreover, the spyder works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to activate the anaconda environment first.

In terminal: `source activate environment_name`, (or `activate environment_name` on windows?)

then `jupyter notebook`

If you don't know the env name, do `conda list`

to restore the default python environment: `source deactivate`

Comment: Thank you so much. And by the way is it possible to have a independent python 3.6.5 and anaconda with 3.6 at the same time? I'm affraid they might overlap

Comment: Yes, you can have two (or more) anaconda environments with different python versions, and/or the same python version, and different packages installed. 
Yes, on mac OS, you can have anaconda alongside other python distributions; for windows, IDK, but I don't see why you could not.

Comment: Thank you because I just affraid might cause some problem just like the visual studio one. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: I just get into another trouble. After doing what you suggested, it appears that the port 8888 is in use again. I don't understand this problem because after I clear cache from my computer the problems seem to come back.

Comment: hummm, you may have several instances of `jupyter notebook` running; maybe try `jupyter notebook stop 8888`, and relaunch? If that fails, maybe close all sessions and try this in terminal: `jupyter notebook --port=8889`; if that does not work either, maybe you ask a new question, and someone else will be able to answer.

Comment: I'm able to fix this problem by resetting my firewall settings. I appeared that after a Windows update the firewall suddenly blocks some of the port, hence, I'm not able to connect to the local server

Comment: ok - I don't have a windows system, so I am afraid I cannot be of much help here, sorry.

Comment: btw thank you for your effort to help me. I have solved my problems